# java.util.regex.PatternRegexSyntaxException

Tags: java, regex

I want to make token on the base of following delimiters
`" \t\n\r,?;.:/!<>%*+=()&\"{}[]-_\'"`

I used both StringTokenizer and the following code but they have not given correct output. In fact, the following code throws exception as well.

```
String [] multiTokenizer = content.split(" \t\n\r,?;.:/!<>%*+=()&\"{}[]-_\'");
```

I have tried putting `\\*` and doing other suggested stuff but could not solve the problem.

Can somebody tell me why the problem occurred and where?

I want tokens to have non of the delimiter doesn't matters if they exist together or separately.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a character class to be able to split on any of these characters:

```
String [] multiTokenizer = content.split("[ \\t\\n\\r,?;.:/!<>%*+=()&\"{}\\[\\]_'-]+");
```

- Note that you must keep unescaped hyphen at 1st or last place in character class or else escape it.
- Also every escape needs double escape in Java regex.
- It is better to use a quantifier `+` to be able to split on multiple occurrences of these special characters.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that

Comment: Which part you didn't get? I have provided you a working regex also.

Comment: [More about character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: We don't need to write `\t` `\n` `\r` with ``\\``. Regex engine will also accept these literals.

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo: that's a good clarification. Though I think better to get used to `\\ ` for escaping in Java

Comment: Your regex fails to compile due to `[]` forming an empty character class. You need to escape them.

Comment: Thanks @nhahtdh for looking into it, It is fixed now.

Comment: It still doesn't remove "?" and "\"

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.